# C# - Pattern for iterating over predicates

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns, iteration

I made a pattern which i dont really like.

It is as the following:

```
List<Element> listOfPossibleResults = getAllPossibleResults();

Element result = findResult(getFirstPriorityElements(listOfPossibleResults));
if (result!= null)
{
 return result;
}

result = findResult(getSecondPriorityElements(listOfPossibleResults));
if (result!= null)
{
 return result;
}

private Element findResult(List<Element> elements) {...};
private List<Element> getFirstPriorityElements(List<Element> elements) {...};
private List<Element> getSecondPriorityElements(List<Element> elements) {...};
```

etc..

Basically i'am creating sublists based on a couple of rules. After creating the sublist, i try and find a specific element in it. If i dont find, i move on to the next priority, and so on.

I would like a solution where i can iterate over these criterias, until i find a solution. But i dont know how to get them to a format which i can iterate over.

Can you guys give me a C# specific solution of the issue?

Comment: Sounds like chain of responsibility. Look at https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility.

Comment: I think you have oversimplified your code. at least write types of each variable and `return type` of the method.

Comment: Edited the question for clarity.

Comment: ok. the first way is to merge your `getFirstPriorityElements` with `getSecondPriorityElements` and having a method like `getPriorityElements` that takes additional parameter like `int priority`.... therefor you can make a loop and iterate with indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Lepijohnny mentioned, you can use `Chain of responsibility` design pattern. For example:

```
abstract class Handler<TRequest, TResult>
{
  protected Handler<TRequest, TResult> successor;

  public void SetSuccessor(Handler<TRequest, TResult> successor)
  {
    this.successor = successor;
  }

  public abstract TResult HandleRequest(TRequest request);
}

class FirstHandler : Handler<List<Element>, Element>
{
  public override void HandleRequest(TRequest request)
  {
    Element result = findResult(getFirstPriorityElements(request));
    if (result == null)
    {
      result = sucessor?.HandleRequest(request);
    }
    return result;
  }

  private Element findResult(List<Element> elements) {...};
  private List<Element> getFirstPriorityElements(List<Element> elements) {...};
}

class SecondHandler : Handler<List<Element>, Element>
{
  public override void HandleRequest(TRequest request)
  {
    Element result = findResult(getSecondPriorityElements(request));
    if (result == null)
    {
      result = sucessor?.HandleRequest(request);
    }
    return result;
  }

  private Element findResult(List<Element> elements) {...};
  private List<Element> getSecondPriorityElements(List<Element> elements) {...};
}
```

Usage:

```
void Example()
{
  // Setup Chain of Responsibility
  var h1 = new FirstHandler();
  var h2 = new SecondHandler();
  h1.SetSuccessor(h2);

  var result = h1.Handle(new List<Element>());
}
```

It's a just quick example. I think it describe how this pattern works and you will be able to adjust it for your needs.

Comment: Great! Thats what i was looking for. Thank you for your time!

Comment: no, i did not try it yet, but i understand how to implement the solution now! :)

Comment: This is a useful pattern but for this case it is far more heavyweight than is necessary and, if I've understood the question properly, more can be abstracted out - LINQ is provided for just such cases where we can use higher order functions to our benefit to make code more declarative.

Comment: @Oly my thoughts exactly when I created my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Am I right that your get__PriorityElements is literally a filter? In that case, it's more declarative and hopefully more readable to treat those like this:

```
Func<Element, bool> isFirstPriority = ...;
var firstPriorityElements = elements.Where(isFirstPriority);
```

And now your overall goal is to extract a single element (or none) from the highest-possible priority subsequence, using a predicate contained in `findResult`? So replace this with an actual predicate

```
Func<Element, bool> isResult = ...;
```

like so. Now you want to look through all the first priority elements for an `isResult` match, then if not found all the second priority elements, etc. This sounds just like a sequence concatenation! So we end up with

```
var prioritisedSequence = elements
    .Where(isFirstPriority)
    .Concat(elements
        .Where(isSecondPriority))
    .Concat....;
```

And finally the result

```
var result = prioritisedSequence
    .FirstOrDefault(isResult);
```

Since `Where` and `Concat` are lazily enumerated this has the benefit that it is declarative while avoiding more work than necessary, and it's lightweight and 'LINQy' as well.

If you want abstract it even more, and anticipate changes in how priorities will be arranged, you could actually make a higher order list for those like this:

```
IEnumerable<Func<Element, bool>> priorityFilters = new[]
{
    isFirstPriority,
    isSecondPriority,
    ...
};
```

and then the concatenation can be performed as an aggregation over that sequence:

```
var prioritisedSequence = priorityFilters
    .Aggregate(
        Enumerable.Empty<Element>(),
        (current, filter) => current.Concat(elements.Where(filter)));
```

This change may make it easier to add new priorities in future, or you may think it clutters and hides the intention of your code.

Answer (score 1):

In the "result" class put a property called "Priority (int)" then:

```
result = listOfPossibleResults.GroupBy(x => x.Priority).OrderBy(x => x.Key);
```

then:

```
return result.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Count() > 0);
```

You will need to fill in the priority of the result items when you first retrieve them.

P.S. I typed the code right here, forgive me if there is a spelling mistake somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The problem is a bit more complicated tho. The reason i didnt write down the exact format of the subset creation is beacuse its more complex than just grouping the elements by priority. My main question is how to iterate over a number of clauses or predicates, and return the result only when an element is found, instead of nullchecking and manually writing them down.

Answer (score 1):

If you could refactor the methods getFirstPriorityElements(List<> list) to a single getPriorityElements(List<> list, int nr) you could do the following

```
method IteratePredicates(List<> list, int nr = 0) 
{
    if (nr>maxpriority) return null;
    return findresult(getPriorityElements(list,nr)) ?? IteratePredicates(list,nr++);
}
```

In a for loop:

```
    method IteratePredicates(List<> list, int nr = 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxpriority; i++)
        {
            var result = findresult(getPriorityElements(list, nr));
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that would work, thank you very much. Im still waiting for answers, because i dont really like recursions on a readability standpoint, and avoid using them as much as i can. Ill mark you if i dont get a more suitible answer for my needs.

Comment: Non-recursion example added

Answer (score 1):

You can treat methods as objects using `Func<T, T>`, and then you can also put them in e.g. an array. Then you can iterate over the array, calling the methods one by one until a result is found.

The solution then becomes:

```
var methods = new Func<List<Element>, List<Element>>[]
    { getFirstPriorityElements, getSecondPriorityElements };

return methods
    .Select(method => findResult(method(listOfPossibleResults)))
    .Where(result => result != null)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is short and readable, works without changing your methods or types, and no need to add classes just for the sake of applying a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the specs pattern 
Here is a sample code:
Create a interface with a criteria:

```
public interface ISpecification<T>
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> Criteria { get; }
}
```

Then create a class that holds your query specs:

```
public class GlobalSongSpecification : ISpecification<Song>
{
    public List<int> GenreIdsToInclude { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    public List<int> AlbumIdsToInclude { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    public List<string> ArtistsToInclude { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public string TitleFilter { get; set; }
    public int MinRating { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Expression<Func<Song, bool>> Criteria
    {
        get
        {
            return s =>
                (!GenreIdsToInclude.Any() || s.Genres.Any(g => GenreIdsToInclude.Any(gId => gId == g.Id))) &&
                (!AlbumIdsToInclude.Any() || AlbumIdsToInclude.Contains(s.AlbumId)) &&
                (!ArtistsToInclude.Any() ||ArtistsToInclude.Contains(s.Artist)) &&
                (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TitleFilter) || s.Title.Contains(TitleFilter)) &&
                s.Rating >= MinRating;
        }
    }
}
```

Create a repository with a method that exposes one that receives ISpecification:

```
 public interface ISongRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Song> List(ISpecification<Song> specification);
    //IQueryable<Song> List();
    Song GetById(int id);
    void Add(Song song);
    IEnumerable<string> AllArtists();
    IEnumerable<Genre> AllGenres();
}
```

And your client code call the GlobalSongSpecification, populates it and pass it to the repository in order to filter by the criteria:

```
public ActionResult Index(List<int> selectedGenres = null, 
        List<string> selectedArtists = null, 
        string titleSearch = null,
        int minRating = 0,
        string filter = null,
        string save = null,
        string playlistName = null)
    {
        if (selectedArtists == null) { selectedArtists = new List<string>(); }
        if (selectedGenres == null) { selectedGenres = new List<int>(); }

        var spec = new GlobalSongSpecification();
        spec.ArtistsToInclude.AddRange(selectedArtists);
        spec.GenreIdsToInclude.AddRange(selectedGenres);
        spec.MinRating = minRating;
        spec.TitleFilter = titleSearch;

        var songs = _songRepository.List(spec);

        //You can work with the filtered data at this point
    }
```

And you populate a razor view or expose it as web api.
The sample code is from pluralsight desing patterns library course [Here(Specification Pattern module)](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/patterns-library/table-of-contents)